# C++ variable used without initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

I am getting this error:

> The variable "thename" is being used without being initialized

Here's my code:

```
char *thename;
cm++;
sprintf(thename, "tutmap%d.map", cm);
```

Comment: @DeadMG answering his question is another option, although I agree with you about his C++ abilities.

Comment: Thumb rule : Always initialize pointer variables; make it  char *thename = NULL; Then work yourself why you are getting a segmentation fault :)

Comment: This question should be tagged C. So that people who write C code can comment on it.

Comment: You have a good compiler: it's saving you from making a bad figure of yourself in front of your teacher. Always pay attention to what your compiler tells you, be it warnings or errors. Assume it is being helpful.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the variable without initializing it, and running this code will be Undefined Behavior.

Perhaps you meant:

```
char thename[42];
cm++;
sprintf(thename, "tutmap%d.map", cm);
```

If you have snprintf, here's a function which documents that you guarantee ("assert") the buffer to be large enough, but then also checks the buffer length and aborts if you made an error:

```
template<int N>
void fixed_sprintf(char (&array)[N], char const *format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  int used = vsnprintf(array, N, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (used == N - 1) {
    throw whatever_exception_type_you_like("buffer too small");
    // or even:
    abort();
  }
}
```

The "fixed" means "fixed-size", not "opposite of broken". :)

Comment: I always liked to include “demons flying out of your nose” as part of Undefined Behavior. OK, we all know that particular outcome is unlikely but it's still a wonderful/horrible image…

Comment: Using fixed-size char buffers is like asking for buffer overflows.

Comment: @delnan: Not when the size you need is fixed.

Comment: @Fred: what if it's a platform with >103 bit integers?

Comment: @ybungalobill: That is a chance I will have to take. Use 10+sizeof(STRINGIZE(INT_MIN))+1 if you're truly paranoid.

Comment: Rather than whinging about fixed-size buffers and complicating things with a dynamic buffer size, instead complicate things with an intelligent string formatter that knows to check the size of a fixed-size buffer.  Perhaps you'll like this edit, @delnan.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared a pointer to a C string but not allocated any memory for it.

If you want stack allocated memory use

```
char thename[buffer_length];
```

If you prefer heap allocation use

```
char *thename = malloc(buffer_length);
```

I know the question is tagged C++ but your code looks more like C to me. Hence the use of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to understand:

```
char *thename;
```

does not initialise `thename`, and then:

```
sprintf(thename, "tutmap%d.map", cm);
```

uses it. With dire results, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing:

```
char *thename;
cm++;
sprintf(thename, "tutmap%d.map", cm);
```

Write:

```
cm++;
std::stringstream stream;     
stream << "tutmap" << cm << ".map";
std::string const name = stream.str();
// and if you really need char* then:
char const* thename = name.c_str();
```

Comment: I don't like: `char const* thename = name.c_str();`. It makes the code hard to maintain as you have an implicit requirement (that is not documented) that name can not be modified (or read in some cases (name[0] may cause a copy in COW implementations)) without `thename` becoming invalid. The only time it is safe to use c_str() is when you pass it as a parameter to a function.

Comment: @Martin: Ok made the `name` const as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *thename = new char[21]; //21 is used for maximum string length of 20
cm++;
sprintf(thename, "tutmap%d.map", cm);
```

Comment: Why new?  Conventionally, a char array of size 20 has a maximum string length of 19.

Comment: To clarify what Fred is saying, the array of 20 chars can hold a string of max-length 19 because of the terminator NUL byte at the end (which must be present, even if it's not “in” the string).

Comment: OK, updated length problem. Using new or the other method depends on the situation the code is running. The old heap and stack story. None of them is better. It just depends!

Comment: @FarshidZaker: Except for small, fixed sizes, prefer a local array *by default* and change to dynamic as needed.

Comment: @Fred: What if he needs to pass the char* thing between several objects? Why create a local and change it while we know it from beginning?

Comment: @FarshidZaker: If you know it's needed, then use it, as I said.  You should still prefer a std::string (or a better type) to a raw char array by default, in that case, however.

Comment: Even on 32bit platform you get undefined behavior if `int cm = -1000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

thename is a pointer that has not been initialized. Change thename to an array of char that will fit the size of the complete string generated by sprintf.